# Alternative to ls in shell-script compatible with nohup

Tags: linux, shell, ls

I have a shell-script which lists all the file names in a directory and store them in a new file.

The problem is that when I execute this script with the nohup command, it lists the first name four times instead of listing the correct names.

Commenting the problem with other programmers they think that the problem may be the `ls` command.

Part of my code is the following:

```
for i in $( ls -1 ./Datasets/); do
    awk  '{print $1}'  ./genes.txt | head -$num_lineas | tail -1 >> ./aux   
    let num_lineas=$num_lineas-1    
done
```

Do you know an alternative to `ls` that works well with nohup?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `ls` to feed the loop, use:

```
for i in ./Datasets/*; do
```

or if subdirectories are of interest

```
for i in ./Datasets/*/*; do
```

Lastly, and more correctly, use `find` if you need the entire tree below `Datasets`:

```
find ./Datasets -type f | while IFS= read -r file; do
    (do stuff with $file)
done
```

Others frown, but there is nothing wrong with also using find as:

```
for file in $(find ./Datasets -type f); do
    (do stuff with $file)
done
```

Just choose the syntax that most closely meets your needs.

Comment: And to get the name of the current file, how would you do? I have the following code: 
    current_file=` ls -1 ./Datasets/ | head -$num_fitxers | tail -1`

Comment: No. The full path/filename is already in `$file` so if you want the filename without the path, use substring extraction `filename="${file##*/}"` and if you just want the path use `thepath="${file%/*}"`.

Comment: You have 2 options. Either read all filenames into an array and sort, or use the sort features of ls. This isn't the preferred manner to use ls, but you can do `for i in $(ls -1 ./Datasets/); do` (that '1' is 'one' not lower-case 'L'). That will give you the files in alphabetical order. The array solution is a bit more involved.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)! A simple `glob` will suffice. Secondly, your `awk | head | tail` chain can be simplified by only printing the first column of the line that you're interested in using awk. Thirdly, you can redirect the output of your loop to a file, rather than using `>>`.

Incorporating all of those changes into your script:

```
for i in Datasets/*; do
    awk  -v n="$(( num_lineas-- ))" 'NR==n{print $1}' genes.txt
done > aux
```

Every time the loop goes round, the value of `$num_lineas` will decrease by 1.

In terms of your problem with `nohup`, I would recommend looking into using something like `screen`, which is known to be a better solution for maintaining a session between logins.

Comment: `screen`, or at least crontab. Good luck to all!